# Animation controller not starting via trigger in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr

Hi I am trying to start an Animation via a trigger in my game but does seem to be working.   I have an object with animation which I want to start when the player enters the "Trigger" zone.

Here is the script:

```
#pragma strict

var animator: Animator;

function Start() {

}
function OnTriggerEnter() {

animator.Play(animator.name);

}


function Update () {

}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Animator.GotoState: State could not be found
>   UnityEngine.Animator:Play(String)

AND

> Invalid Layer Index '-1'
>   UnityEngine.Animator:Play(String)

The animation controller name is: AnimControle.controller

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The value you have passed in the `Play()` method _animator.name_ is not valid, you need to mention a valid state from your animator.

Comment: Note sure what you mean? can you explain to me maybe?

Comment: In `Unity` when you add an `Animator` component you make different states for it right? For example: _Idle_ or _Jumping_. That's what you have to say to the `Play()` method. But instead you have mentioned `animator.name` which is not a valid state.

Comment: a noob comment but shouldnt you say in start `animator = GetComponent("Animator");`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set animation parameters correctly.
I suggest you this guide. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html

Answer (score 0):

For Triggers try this function :

```
animator.SetTrigger("carNorth");// Given that you already have a Trigger named carNorth
```

Also what @Hristo said is correct. You pass the name of the Trigger in the function arguments. Make sure you defined the Trigger in the Animation Window before passing it.
[image]

for the function you are using see the offical Unity documents 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html